# C# How to remove the Shadow (see picture below) after selected in Richtextbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Background: The `Richtextbox` is a control component which is I found on Internet, the code is

```
public TransparentLabel()
{
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, false);
    this.TextChanged += TransparentLabel_TextChanged;
    this.VScroll += TransparentLabel_TextChanged;
}
void TransparentLabel_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.ForceRefresh();
}
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams;
        parms.ExStyle |= 0x20;  // Turn on WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        return parms;
    }
}
public void ForceRefresh()
{
    this.UpdateStyles();
}
```

1. How to remove the *Shadow* (the highlight text) after selected by clicking the box or anywhere?
2. How to edit to hide the vertical scrollbar?

Remark: 1. The *Shadow* disappear when scroll up or down  2. This `Richtextbox` is for background transparency purpose

Comment: _The Richtextbox is a control component which is I found on Internet_ What does this mean? The RichTextBox is part of WPF controls (don't know about WinForms). Which kind of application are you developing? WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `HilightBrush` to `Transparent`?

Comment: @AlbertoSolano I am using WinForms. what I am trying to say about the control component is after adding the code above in a class and build, it will show on the toolbox, and i can use it like the normal windows Forms.

Comment: @MarkL I understood, now it's clear. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the `RichTextBox` control of WPF ([System.Windows.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx)):

```
this.richTextBox.SelectionBrush = null; //to remove the text highlighting
this.richTextBox.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden; //to remove the vertical scrollbar
```

Considering instead the `RichTextBox` control of Windows Forms ([System.Windows.Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)), it's not possible to change the color of selected text. For further details, read [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/692bb113-737d-462c-adef-dffc465a1282/richtextbox-selection-color?forum=winforms).

You can hide the vertical scrollbar in this way (only the horizontal scrollbar will be visible):

```
this.richTextBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Horizontal;
```

Comment: it seems can't remove the color of selected text directly. I add in
this.SelectionChanged += Refresh;
and it seem can work, every time change the selected will refresh or updatestyle, so that the color will be gone.

for the verticalscrollbar, if i change to Horizontal, it seem cant scroll down anymore. thx